# Linear Algebra Midterm Review Questions

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reviewing for a midterm this week and completed these problems out of an old textbook I found. I was looking for verification that I completed some of them accurately and a step in the right direction for this which I do not understand or got incorrect.

True/False

(a) If b is in the Col A, then solution to Ax = b is the same as the least-square solution to Ax = b.
True

(c) If det(1n×n − A) = 0 means that there is a nonzero vector x such that Ax = x.
Uncertain

(d) If columns of a square matrix A form a basis of R^n they show that ATA = 1n×n.
Uncertain

(g) The adjoint of a matrix A may be invertible, even if A is not invertible.
False, definition of adjoint formula

Comment: Too many questions. One step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

For C- True

$\det(I - A) = 0 \implies \text{ there exists a } \vec{v} \neq \vec0 \text{ such that } \vec0 = (I-A)\vec v = I\vec v - A\vec v \implies A\vec v= I\vec v = \vec{v}$

For D- False in general, it is true when the columns of A are orthornormal.

For f- False

As you said it means the matrix is not invertable, and hence its determinant must be zero.

All your other answers are correct.